# Automating IF and then statement in sas using macro in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

I have a data where I have various types of loan descriptions, there are at least 100 of them.

I have to categorise them into various buckets using if and then function. Please have a look at the data for reference

```
data des;     
    set desc;      
if loan_desc in ('home_loan','auto_loan')then product_summary ='Loan';     
if loan_desc in ('Multi') then product_summary='Multi options';     
run;
```

For illustration I have shown it just for two loan description, but i have around 1000 of different loan_descr that I need to categorise into different buckets.

How can I categorise these loan descriptions in different buckets without writing the product summary and the loan_desc again and again in the code which is making it very lengthy and time consuming

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Another option for categorizing is using a format. This example uses a manual statement, but you can also create a format from a dataset if you have the to/from values in a dataset. As indicated by @Tom this allows you to change only the table and the code stays the same for future changes.

One note regarding your current code, you're using If/Then rather than If/ElseIf. You should use If/ElseIf because then it terminates as soon as one condition is met, rather than running through all options.

```
proc format;
value $ loan_fmt
'home_loan', 'auto_loan' = 'Loan'
'Multi' = 'Multi options';
run;

data want;
set have;

loan_desc = put(loan, $loan_fmt.);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a mapping exercise like this, the best technique is to use a mapping table.  This is so the mappings can be changed without changing code, among other reasons.

A simple example is shown below:

```
/* create test data */
data desc (drop=x);
  do x=1 to 3;
    loan_desc='home_loan'; output;
    loan_desc='auto_loan'; output;
    loan_desc='Multi'; output;
    loan_desc=''; output;
  end;
data map;
  loan_desc='home_loan'; product_summary ='Loan        '; output;
  loan_desc='auto_loan'; product_summary ='Loan'; output;
  loan_desc='Multi'; product_summary='Multi options'; output;
run;

/* perform join */
proc sql;
create table des as 
  select a.*
    ,coalescec(b.product_summary,'UNMAPPED') as product_summary
  from desc a
  left join map b
  on a.loan_desc=b.loan_desc;
```

There is no need to use the macro language for this task (I have updated the question tag accordingly).

Comment: Do we have to run the do loop 100 times if there are 100 variables

Comment: The do loop was only there to create a test 'have' table, as none was provided!  To expand on your point though, whilst @reeza is correct to suggest using a format (a very good way to apply a mapping table in the described instance), if you do indeed have 100 variables to map (to a single key) then a join (as I describe) would be better.  I suggest though that you ask a new question with more detail of what you are actually trying to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

Already good solutions have been proposed (I like @Reeza's `proc format` solution), but here's another route which also minimizes coding.

### Generate sample data

```
data have;
    loan_desc="home_loan"; output;
    loan_desc="auto_loan"; output;
    loan_desc="Multi"; output;
    loan_desc=""; output;
run;
```

### Using `PROC SQL`'s `case` expression

This way doesn't allow, to my knowledge, having several criteria on a single `when` line, but it really simplifies coding since the resulting variable's name needs to be written down only once.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select 
      loan_desc,
      case loan_desc
        when "home_loan" then "Loan"
        when "auto_loan" then "Loan"
        when "Multi" then "Multi options"
        else "Unknown"
      end as product_summary
    from have;
quit;
```

Otherwise, using the following syntax is also possible, giving the same results:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select 
      loan_desc,
      case 
        when loan_desc in ("home_loan", "auto_loan") then "Loan"
        when loan_desc = "Multi" then "Multi options"
        else "Unknown"
      end as product_summary
    from have;
quit;
```